# Pointer initialization with new keyword and without it

Tags: c++, pointers

When I try to declare in another way a pointer I try to use the new keyword and give it a try:

```
#include<iostream>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main ()
{
    int *p = new int;
    *p = 5;
    cout << *p << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

but when I try to declare the same pointer but without the new keyword it gives me an error like the code below:

```
#include<iostream>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main ()
{
    int *p;
    *p = 5;
    cout << *p << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

So what is the reason for that error and what is the difference between the two ways?

Comment: It isn' the declaration; its the lack of initialization or assignment to a viable determinate address that can be dereferenced. The second code example invokes *undefined behavior* by dereferencing an *indeterminate* pointer. Consider yourself fortunate it gives you an error (which, mysteriously, you didn't bother providing in your question). UB is notorious for appearing to work... or not... or maybe, which is *not* the kind of thing you want to submit to a grader, or worse, a paying customer.

Comment: compilers can diagnose this, you just need to tell them to do so: https://godbolt.org/z/v8EvrPWrq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should know the differences.

```
int *p;
```

Here, `p` is just a variable on the stack. It hasn't been initialized so it does not point to a specific location on the memory. Thus when you dereference it and assign a value to the underlying location you are invoking some undefined behavior. In other words, you haven't yet allocated any space on the heap to store an `int`. So here:

```
*p = 5;
```

you are probably assigning the value 5 to a location that does not belong to your program.

Now here:

```
int *p = new int;
*p = 5;
```

this is fine. The `new` operator will reserve 4 bytes on the heap memory and return its address and that address gets stored in the `p` and now `p` contains an actual and legal address of a block of memory capable of storing an `int`. So it is safe to dereference `p` and assign a value to the underlying location.

**Important note**: You should almost never deal with `new`/`delete` or `new[]`/`delete[]` operators and raw pointers. Instead, you should use [smart pointers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/smart-pointers-modern-cpp?view=msvc-170) and stick to [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) as much as possible.
Therefore, the correct way of doing the above would be like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<memory>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main ()
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> p { std::make_unique<int>( 5 ) };
    cout << *p << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

However, using any type of pointers is wasteful in this case since you can also store small types on the stack:

```
int num { 5 };
```

This is the preferred way of storing values unless you are desperate to use dynamic memory allocations (for some reason, like maybe you want an object to have dynamic storage duration, or maybe the object is large and won't fit on the stack).

Comment: your important note is a little misleading. There shouldnt be any pointer in this code. Why not just `int p = 5;` ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Yes right. I added the necessary info.

Answer (score 0):

`new int` occupies a new memory space on the heap, and `p` points to that memory space. But on the second example, you didn't specify where `p` points to (so `p` can point to anywhere, but you try to assign the memory address `p` points, so it cause undefined behaviour.